# How do you remember mates with names?

Tags: checkmate, memorization

I am working on the Yusupov series. In the first book he introduces Anastasia and Arabian among others. What I am a little uncertain about is the following issues.

- How do you remember them?
- How do you classify them?

I guess I am unsure about what defines a mate, especially when they are more vague than smothered/Philidor. Anastasia for example is quite vague. Are all rook+knight mates Arabian mate?

Comment: Don't worry about the name. Remember the patterns the pieces make and how to get there, that's much more important.

Comment: Through repeated exposure to the names. You might find in your post-game analysis that you missed some mating tactics, so you go and look up mating patterns and come across some that you'd seen before but forgotten, and you see their name again. If you have friends that also play Chess, and you discuss Chess with them, some of those mating patterns will come up naturally, and, at least for me, when they come up in a natural setting like that instead of an academic one I find I am much more likely to remember. Maybe you watch a YT video and a youtuber talks about them.

Comment: Names are useful for talking about them.  I don't think about them when I am playing.

Answer (score 5):

> How do you remember them?

Generally speaking I make no effort to remember their names because they have very little use. In terms of remembering the patterns they are like any tactical motif like forks, pins, skewers, overloading, etc.

> How do you classify them?

Again, except for obscure things like writing a book this is almost useless. Classifying them doesn't help me play better so I don't waste my time trying to do that.

Answer (score 2):

As @Brian Towers said, remembering their names is nearly obsolete. But categorising them may help in recognising them, especially when an individual is new to chess.

To checkout the named mating patterns, explore this link: https://lichess.org/practice

But I would suggest you to consider them as miscellaneous tactics, as there can be many mating patterns possible other than the named ones.